# Simplified version of if-conditional statement with array and don't have to declare array[0] | array[1] | array[2]?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

These codes are already working and I just want to simplify it. This is a query of a custom post type called "File Upload". I'm using ACF fronted form to create these posts and has the function to select which category can the post be seen. My condition here is if the "current post" has a category that matches the category set to display the file upload, it shows the file upload .

```
<div class="sd-files sd-box">
    <?php 
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'file-upload',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $uploads = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $uploads->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <h4>Workshop Manual Download</h4>
        <?php while ( $uploads->have_posts() ) {
            $uploads->the_post(); ?>
            <?php // The Terms / File Category
            $terms = get_field('vh_vehicle_brand'); 
            if( $terms ) { 
                if (!is_array($terms)) {
                    $terms = array($terms);
                } } $term1 = $terms[0]; $term2 = $terms[1]; $term3 = $terms[2]; $term4 = $terms[3]; $term5 = $terms[4]; $term6 = $terms[5]; $term7 = $terms[6]; $term8 = $terms[7]; $term9 = $terms[8]; $term10 = $terms[9]; $term11 = $terms[10]; $term12 = $terms[11]; $term13 = $terms[12]; ?>

            <?php if($curPostCatID == $term1 || $curPostCatID == $term2 || $curPostCatID == $term3 || $curPostCatID == $term4 || $curPostCatID == $term5 || $curPostCatID == $term6 || $curPostCatID == $term7 || $curPostCatID == $term8 || $curPostCatID == $term9 || $curPostCatID == $term10 || $curPostCatID == $term11 || $curPostCatID == $term12) { ?>
                    <div class="file-list"><a href="<?php the_field('vh_file_path'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- Files -->
```

Comment: use `in_array()` function: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  if($curPostCatID === $term) { ?>
   // conditional output here
  <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help.

Comment: although it works but its better to use `in_array($curPostCatID, $term)` instead `foreach`